# Add all elements to the another List in java?

Tags: java, list, session, arraylist

I am trying to implement "add to cart" concept like any e-commerce website on the basis of "productId". when i am calling this controller, it's add only last element which user added to the list instead of all product list.

```
@RequestMapping("/addcart/{list.productId}")
public String addCart(@PathVariable("list.productId") Integer productId, Model m, HttpSession session) {

    List<Product> cartlist = productDao.findById(productId);
    List<Product> useradd = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Product e : cartlist) {
        useradded.add(e);
    }

    session.setAttribute("sessioncartview", useradded);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

i found only one product which was last added, not all product list.  in "useradded". i want to add all elements in the list i.e. "useradded" object and after that bind with session. how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are creating a new `useradded` list every time when this method is called.

Instead of doing

```
List<Product> useradd = new ArrayList<>();
```

you can get the `useradd` from the session and only create a new instance if it is not there.

```
List<Product> useradd = session.get("sessioncartview");
if (useradd == null) {
    useradd = new ArrayList<>();
}
```